# Error on appending dictionary to mysql table

Tags: python, mysql

I'm querying a table in a mysql database and want to append results to another table in the same database, but I'm getting an error that I can't seem to shake off.

Thus far I've

- connected and executed a sql query in the mysql db
- saved results to a pandas dataframe
- tried to use to_sql which throws a module error then
  some other errors...
- next converted dataframe to a dictionary
- tried to append dictionary to mysql table

Code:

```py
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

dbServerName    = "..."
dbUser          = "..."
dbPassword      = "..."
dbName          = "..."

connObject = pymysql.connect(dbServerName, dbUser, dbPassword, dbName)
sqlQuery = """select id, uniqueUserId, time from searchResult where time>'2018-02-01' and time<'2018-03-2' limit 5"""
df = pd.read_sql(sqlQuery, connObject)
df['time'] = df['time'].astype(str)
# df.to_sql('test', con=conn, if_exists='append')
dfDict = df.to_dict(orient='list')

cursor = connObject.cursor()
table = 'test'
placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(dfDict))
columns = ', '.join(dfDict.keys())
sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (table, columns, placeholders)
cursor.execute(sql, list(dfDict.values()))
```

I expect the code to append the dictionary to the table named 'test'. But instead I receive the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-86395db9a7b9> in <module>
      4 columns = ', '.join(dfDict.keys())
      5 sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (table, columns, placeholders)
----> 6 cursor.execute(sql, list(dfDict.values()))

InternalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

dfDict contents looks something like this:

```
{'id': [39457,
  39458,
  39459,
  39460,
  39461,
  ...],
  'time': ['2018-03-01 00:00:05',
  '2018-03-01 00:00:09',
  '2018-03-01 00:00:10',
  '2018-03-01 00:00:15',
  '2018-03-01 00:00:17',
  ...],
  'uniqueUserId': ['123abc-x123-y123-z123-1234567xyz',
  '123abc-x1415-y3264-z1343-13452xyz',
  '3413dgwe-x1143-124124-4214af-125wfag',
  'lk23h5l-l23k5h-2l3jk4-l15h-1po5j',
  'a987sfa-23kh4-n21m4nb1-1j5lkj2b3-kho7v62o',
  ...]}
```

Other info:

- Python 3.7.3
- Mac OS Mojave 10.14
- MySQL 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does `print(sql)` look like? That is where the problem may be.

Comment: `print(sql)` returns `INSERT INTO test (id, uniqueUserId, time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)`

Comment: have you ever heard about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov - yes. Your point?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (table, columns, placeholders)` doesn't look safe

Comment: Provide the generated SQL; I think you will discover the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line should be:

```
cursor.executemany(sql, args)
```

where args is computed thus:

```
v = list(dfDict.values())
args = [[v[j][i] for j in range(len(v))] for i in range(len(v[0]))]
```

Yielding for args:

```
[[39457, '2018-03-01 00:00:05', '123abc-x123-y123-z123-1234567xyz'], [39458, '2018-03-01 00:00:09', '123abc-x1415-y3264-z1343-13452xyz'], ...
```

Comment: Or redesign the structure of the data to send to the SQL statement.

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for the final square bracket in `args` for some reason...

Comment: @AK91: Right you are: I was missing  a `)`. I had fiddled around a couple of times in interactive Python and copied and and pasted the wrong line. Sorry about that.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson - you sir, are an absolute LEGEND, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put multiple new tuples into a relation in one go, I am quite sure you need to use `MySQLCursor.executemany()` instead of `MySQLCursor.execute()`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Alternatively you can iterate through the three lists in that dictionary and do a single `MySQLCursor.execute()` for each set of data.

Comment: I added `cursor.executemany(sql, list(dfDict.values()))` but got the following error: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: Is list(dfDict.values()) in the format [(value, value, value), (value, value, value),...]?

Comment: it's not...it's [[value, value, value, value, value ...... , value ] , [value, value, value......, value], [value, value, value, value......, value]]

Comment: According to the documentation (link in my answer) the data format required is a list of tuples. Each tuple in this list represents a to be row in the table. You have to transform your dictionary of lists into that format before you can proceed.